# JSP Page update with constant data from Arduino

Tags: ajax, jsp, udp, arduino

I am interfacing a Arduino with Java. I have a JSP page that should display the constant data coming from Arduino via UDP. I have achieved the communication via Arduino! However I need to update the page as feeds. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance